# populate div kinda like what innerhtml does in js

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I have some c# code and in my html I have a div like:

```
<div id="xyz"></div>
```

I want to populate some thing within that div, when a method is called.
I am using the following code

```
public MainPage()
        {


    InitializeComponent();

            HtmlDocument htmlDocTimeListner = HtmlPage.Document;
            HtmlElement htmlElementListener = htmlDocTimeListner.GetElementById("xyz");


        }
```

being new to .net and C#..not sure what to do here. In JS I would have done the following

```
htmlElementListner.getElementById("xyz").innerHTML = "my new text to populate in the div";
```

How would I achieve the same results in .net?

Comment: Are you using asp.net? or asp.net mvc or something else?

Comment: SMF player with silverlight 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
htmlElementListener.SetProperty("innerHTML", "my new text to populate in the div");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish the same thing in Silverlight by first retrieving the HTMLElement by Id:

```
HTMLElement divElement = HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("xyz");

divElement.SetProperty("innerHTML", "new inner html");
```